# How do I recover my deleted keystore password

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I had this screen pop up

[image]

And I had forgotten my password so I clicked reset button thinking it might fix the problem only to later to remember what was the passoword. 
My question is , By resetting the password , did I accidentally also deleted my key store password and my key password ?

Because now I get this:

[image]

Is there any way to recover from this?
And if not , Is it possible to re upload my application to the same spot in google store and keep all the comments and stuff related to my application ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't restore your password or upload your application to the same spot to google store: [Docs from google](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key)

Sorry for a bad news.